# Android navigation popBackStack in action has different behavior from findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.f1, false)

Tags: android, navigation, action, back, fragment-backstack

I'm using Android navigation with safeArgs.

I have fragment 1 F1 with TabLayout.
I have fragment 2 F2 with the button which should navigate to fragment F1 and clear the back stack history.

If I use on the back button simple code without `navigation(action)`, it works well and it even goes to the last selected tab which is what I want.

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
    v.findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.f1, false)
}
```

If I have defined action and use it as I expect to simulate behavior above it works slightly differently.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_F2_to_F1"
    app:destination="@id/f1"
    app:popUpTo="@id/f1"
    app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
```

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
    val action = MyDirections.action_F2_to_F1()
    v.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

The app navigates to the F1 but it also forgot the last selected tab. I know I can keep the selected tab in ViewModel, but frankly, it's really painful and to make it work.

Any suggestion on how to handle navigate action correctly?

Comment: When you use `app:destination="@id/f1"`, you're creating a new instance of `f1` and not just popping back to it. Why do you have that line at all?

Comment: You made my day. Thank you.